# How to find out max number of concurrent requests per second that server could handle in Jmeter

Tags: performance, jmeter, load, jmeter-plugins

I would like to load test https://app-staging.servespark.com site. I have completed scripts on Jmeter for login and am able to go to any page.

How can find out the max number of concurrent requests per second that the server could handle in Jmeter?

Is it possible in the Jmeter? Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to conduct a [Stress Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Stress_testing), something like:

1. Start with 1 user
2. [Gradually increase the load](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-the-ultimate-guide) at the same time looking into the following charts:

   - [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime)
   - [Response Times Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseTimesOverTime)
   - [Transactions Per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond)
3. At the beginning the response time should not change and the throughput (number of transactions per second) should increase by the same factor as the number of users increase
4. At certain stage of test you will notice that response time will start growing and the number of transactions per second will go down. This will indicate a [bottleneck](https://www.quora.com/What-is-bottleneck-in-performance-testing)
5. You may continue increasing the load to see at which stage the errors will start occurring
6. And finally you can decrease the load gradually as well to see if the application gets back to normal when the load comes down (i.e. errors disappear, throughput grows, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this;
https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/

And ramp up the users to a value higher than expected.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback. I have tried it but I am not clear about your last line "And ramp up the users to a value higher than expected."
Please find the result on the Jmeter.

https://prnt.sc/1tpv0qb
https://prnt.sc/1tpv2h8

 Could you please help me how can calculate the maximum user concurrent requests per second that the server could handle?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Error percentage increases if I increase concurrency value. Here is the result
https://prnt.sc/1tpxe1b
https://prnt.sc/1tpx8w
Why the error percentage is increasing?
In the limited ramp-up time, Jmeter could not execute the API. Something like that?
Is it possible to find out concurrent requests per second?

Comment: You can see the "transactions per second" in the test results. 

Save your JTL file by adding a [simple data writer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) to your script and then [generate a HTML report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html). 

[Example of HTML chart](https://jmeter.apache.org/images/screenshots/dashboard/report_transactions_per_second.png)

Also; both of the screenshots you added look the same, not sure what you are referring to regarding the error percentage. Would likely need to see your logs.